# Use cauchy convergence theorem to prove that following sequences are convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

I dont understand how xn - xm = highlighted part. 
isnt it should be

$$ a_{n}q^{n} -  a_{m}q^{m} $$ ?

I understnad other steps. but I dont understnad how solution got highlited part.

Comment: what..? how |x 5 −x 2 | = can be answer like that .. ? 

isn't it should be a3q3 + a4q4 + a5q5  ?????

Comment: Sorry, you're righ, I meant plus but i write minus.

Comment: but thank you ! I understand now !!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

$$\begin{align*}
x_n&=a_0+a_1q+\ldots+a_mq^m+a_{m+1}q^{m+1}+\ldots+a_nq^n\\
x_m&=a_0+a_1q+\ldots+a_mq^m\\ \hline
x_n-x_m&=\phantom{a_0+a_1q+\ldots+a_mq^m+}\;\,a_{m+1}q^{m+1}+\ldots+a_nq^n
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you so much ! but by the way M(q^n  + q^n-1 ) is equal to M q^m+1 ( 1- q^n-m) / 1-q 

is this kind of formular?

Comment: @KwangiYu: That’s just taking the sum of a finite geometric series: $$q_{m+1}+\ldots+q_n =q^{m+1}(1+\ldots+q^{n-(m+1)}) =q^{m+1}(1+\ldots+q^{n-m-1})\;,$$ and $$1+\ldots+q^{n-m-1}=\frac{1-q^{n-m}}{1-q}\;.$$